# Leaflet JS: popup options declaration fails in IE8, but is ok in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: leaflet

I am using the latest LeafletJS library to display a popup with certain popop options on a map.

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but **fails in IE8** with the error message:

> Invalid argument. leaflet.js, Line 6, Character 14452

which is:

```
i=Math.min(i,this.options.maxWidth),i=Math.max(i,this.options.minWidth),e.width=i+1+"px",e.whiteSpace="",e.height=""
```

The problem obviously seems to be with the **popupOptions declaration** - when uncommenting them, no js error occurs in IE8, but of course the options won't be applied either.

So I wonder, what's wrong with the syntax?

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    var popupContent = '...';

    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
    }

    var popupOptions =
    {
        'minWidth': '491px',
        'maxWidth': '491px',
        'closeButton': false
    }

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that line, the minWidth and maxWidth options get fed to Math.max. But yours are no numbers, since they have `px` added to them.

So it should be

```
var popupOptions =
{
    'minWidth': '491',
    'maxWidth': '491',
    'closeButton': false
}
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-options